# Zonal statistics error - Algorithm Zonal Statistics starting... DatasetReadAsArray() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interleave'

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, zonal-statistics

After updating QGIS to 2.18.28 I cannot use Zonal Statistics. As soon as I use it (Raster EPSG 25830 and Polygon 25830), I get the following error message "Algorithm Zonal Statistics starting...

> DatasetReadAsArray() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interleave'
>   See log for more details"

Can anyone reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling all GDAL libaries...it works.